# Naudio produces wierd noise with ffmpeg

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg, naudio

Hi there I was trying to make a music player in c# using the `windows form` and I ended up something like this -

```cs
var ffmpeg = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "ffmpeg",
                Arguments = $@"-loglevel panic -i ""path/to/my-music.mp3"" -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 44100 pipe:1",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true
            }); 
            var p = new RawSourceWaveStream(ffmpeg.StandardOutput.BaseStream,new WaveFormat(44100 , 16, 1));
waveOutDevice.Init(p);
waveOutDevice.Play();
```

But it seems to produce some weird cracking noises , I have been trying it out since 2 days but couldn't get a fix, Any help ?

Comment: With `-ac 2`, shouldn't it be `(44100, 16, 2)`? In any case save ffmpeg output to file. Load that and check if you get the same result?

Comment: yeah thanks for your help but I tried that it gives the same output and when I save it to file it was clear and good.

Comment: @Gyan's troubleshooting tips are good. But apart from that I'd be a little surprised if this works reliably anyway as playing audio is a pull model, whereas ffmpeg is presumably pushing to the output stream, so not sure how that would work internally if ffmpeg created WAV data too quickly or slowly.